# how can i put a python scrpit on a cloud?(with a csv and a sqlite file)

Tags: python, web, server, cloud

i have written a python chatbot (it is a .py file).this python file generates a csv and a sqlite file.i want to put my python file on a cloud running.how can i do this so i will leave it running and generates files there.i also tried to put them on a python host but it didn't work.

```
def main():
    while True:
              ....

                time.sleep(5)


            # Export data into CSV file
                print ("Exporting data into CSV............")
                ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you would like to look into Flask module for python to create a basic web server.

Run 'pip install Flask' in any command or terminal window
 *(assuming you have python installed and added to your environment 'Path')*.

This might get you started.

E. Here is a link which might help (you need to run the app route - likely just on your localhost and then build pages from there with names after the initial '/', for example - http://127.0.0.1/index):

https://pythonspot.com/flask-web-app-with-python/

Comment: thanks! i read anythin i found about flask. the problem is my project is not a web application.and it's not giong to show anything in a browser.i just want my code to run somwhere on some server or coud